# DOM traversal from a span element inside an anchor to list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I can't figure how to travers the DOM, starting from `<span class = "open-menu-link">`, I want to reach `<ul class="sub-menu">` .

The script

```
<script> $('.open-menu-link').click(function(e){
                                      alert(e.currentTarget);
                                    });
</script>
```

return a Object HTMLSpanElement, but if I code `e.currentTarget.parentNode;` it returns `http://localhost/mysite/home.php`. Doing `e.currentTarget.children;` I get Object HTMLCollection, but if I try `e.currentTarget.children[1]` I get undefined... so how can I reach `<ul class="sub-menu">`?
The snippet is the follow:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#about">Haschildren <span class = "open-menu-link">+</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#link1">Child 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link2">Child 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link3">Child 3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, please tag your question as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
$('.open-menu-link').click(function(e){ 
 console.log(e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling);
 console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[1]);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#about">Haschildren <span class="open-menu-link">+</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#link1">Child 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link2">Child 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link3">Child 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

There are couple of options:

```
$('.open-menu-link').click(function(e){ 
    console.log(e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling);
    console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[1]);
});
```

Comment: @AlessandraRefinale, I've updated my answer with a working code, click on `run code snippet` and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

The `<span class = "open-menu-link">` in your code has only one child i.e text node + this is the reason why `e.currentTarget.children[1]` is giving you undefined. 
Coming to the dom traversal, you should start with node `<li class="menu-item-has-children">` . Well that is what I can infer from your question.

Comment: Oh,now it's more clear.... thank you! But I have to click on the "+" to open the menu....By the way, if I put the span outside the anchor (just before <ul class="sub-menu">) , I can reach the parent and then the childrens, but doing it in my way I can easily align the "+" with the "Haschildren" text, instead of having troubles with the css...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preventDefault()` because you'r class is a link. By clicking, it'll redirect you to the link.

```js
$('.open-menu-link').click(function(e) {
  console.log($(this).parent().next())
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#work">Work</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#about">Haschildren <span class = "open-menu-link">+</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#link1">Child 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#link2">Child 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#link3">Child 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the `ul` node can be reached regardless of whether the even is prevented or not

Comment: @Maximus Updated the answer